# Android google map inflateException Binary Xml file

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

i working google map.i successfully create google map.i can add marker in google map.at the moment everythink is ok but i have another error.i use fragments.when i go mapFragment again i have inflateException .i have no idea what am i doing wrong this is a my java code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.strada_contact, container,
            false);
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity().getBaseContext());

    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status,
                getActivity(), requestCode);
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getActivity()
                .getFragmentManager();
        MapFragment myMapFragment = (MapFragment) myFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.pointMap);
        googleMap = myMapFragment.getMap();
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);

        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(
                latitude, longitude));
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14);
        googleMap.moveCamera(center);
        googleMap.animateCamera(zoom);
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("StradaCafe");
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker));

        googleMap.addMarker(marker);

    }}
```

and this is a my xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mapstreet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="street" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mapcountry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mapstreet"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mapstreet"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="mapcountry" />


</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mapimages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0000"
         />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/pointMap"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mapimages"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As i said i have error  when i go again my googleMap fragment only
this is a my logcat error

[image]

if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: you should extend FragmentActivity instead of activity this is the primary cause of the error

Comment: public class StradaContact extends Fragment i use fragment sir.

Comment: thats the problem it should be StradaContact extends FragmentActivity you cant have google map in a fragment

Comment: i understood,but i use slide menu and if i change this fragment with fragmentactivity how i can then replace this fragmentactivy? getSupportFragmentManager()
     .beginTransaction()
     .replace(R.id.content_frame, StradaContact.newInstance(),
       StradaContact.TAG).commit();